# Is it possibile to assing the result of a function using an object to a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript-objects

I'm trying to get information about the move of a mouse. I found a working code here: github.com/ajlkn/jquery.touch.

I'm using a html document with that script, which display the information I need about the move of a mouse.
But I need to assign that information to a variable of a PHP code and I didn't succeed to understand how to do.

```
var Pad = {
    padElem : null,
    elems: null,

    init: function() {
        Pad.padElem = $("#pad");

        Pad.padElem.find(".pad-elem").bind("mousedown touchstart", function(event) {
            Pad.id = $(event.target).parent().attr("id")
        })

        Pad.padElem
            .touch({
                trackDocument: true,
                trackDocumentNormalize: true,
                preventDefault: {
                    drag: true,
                    swipe: true
                }
            })
            .on('swipeLeft', function(e, o) {
                _output('Left - Dist: ' + Math.round(o.distance) + ', Dur: ' + o.duration + ', V: ' + Math.round(o.velocity)+', ID: ' + Pad.id);
                Pad.id = null;
            })
            .on('swipeRight', function(e, o) {
                _output('Right - Dist: ' + Math.round(o.distance) + ', Dur: ' + o.duration + ', V: ' + Math.round(o.velocity)+', ID: ' + Pad.id);
                Pad.id = null;
            });
    },
};

function _output(s) {
    $("#output").html(s);
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: PHP only runs on the server, before the page is sent to the browser.  If you want to send something to PHP to run a script, then you either re-load the page ("postback") or use AJAX to send to another script on the server and get back results that JavaScript running on the client (browser) can use to update the page.

Comment: Where is your PHP file? What's its name?

Comment: @DaveS my knowing of JavaScript is not enough to do what you say. Could you mention a link where I can find some examples or any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Google "html AJAX" for many tutorials